# Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "visible: function (){return NeedPaging }" Message: NeedPaging is not defined

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "visible: function (){return NeedPaging }"
Message: NeedPaging is not defined
    at visible (eval at parseBindingsString (knockout-3.4.2.js:68), :3:60)
    at update (knockout-3.4.2.js:104)
    at function.a.B.i (knockout-3.4.2.js:73)
    at Function.Uc (knockout-3.4.2.js:52)
    at Function.Vc (knockout-3.4.2.js:51)
    at Function.U (knockout-3.4.2.js:51)
    at Object.a.m.a.B (knockout-3.4.2.js:49)
    at knockout-3.4.2.js:73
    at Object.r (knockout-3.4.2.js:11)
    at m (knockout-3.4.2.js:72)

I'm stuck any help would be great thank you in advance.
I'm only getting this error in production however in my local it is working just fine I'm not sure what I'm missing. It looks like the comment is being removed which is giving me the error.

```
$(function () {
"use strict";   

var PagingVm = function (options) {
    var self = this;
    self.PageSize = ko.observable(options.pageSize);
    self.CurrentPage = ko.observable(1);
    self.TotalCount = ko.observable(options.totalCount);
    self.PageCount = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        return Math.ceil(self.TotalCount() / self.PageSize());
    });

    self.SetCurrentPage = function (page) {
        if (page < self.FirstPage)
            page = self.FirstPage;

        if (page > self.LastPage())
            page = self.LastPage();

        self.CurrentPage(page);
    };

    self.FirstPage = 1;
    self.LastPage = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        return self.PageCount();
    });

    self.NextPage = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        var next = self.CurrentPage() + 1;
        if (next > self.LastPage())
            return null;
        return next;
    });

    self.PreviousPage = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        var previous = self.CurrentPage() - 1;
        if (previous < self.FirstPage)
            return null;
        return previous;
    });

    self.NeedPaging = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        return self.PageCount() > 1;
    });

    self.NextPageActive = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        return self.NextPage() != null;
    });

    self.PreviousPageActive = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        return self.PreviousPage() != null;
    });

    self.LastPageActive = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        return (self.LastPage() !== self.CurrentPage());
    });

    self.FirstPageActive = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        return (self.FirstPage !== self.CurrentPage());
    });

    // this should be odd number always
    var maxPageCount = 7;

    self.generateAllPages = function () {
        var pages = [];
        for (var i = self.FirstPage; i <= self.LastPage(); i++)
            pages.push(i);

        return pages;
    };

    self.generateMaxPage = function () {
        var current = self.CurrentPage();
        var pageCount = self.PageCount();
        var first = self.FirstPage;

        var upperLimit = current + parseInt((maxPageCount - 1) / 2);
        var downLimit = current - parseInt((maxPageCount - 1) / 2);

        while (upperLimit > pageCount) {
            upperLimit--;
            if (downLimit > first)
                downLimit--;
        }

        while (downLimit < first) {
            downLimit++;
            if (upperLimit < pageCount)
                upperLimit++;
        }

        var pages = [];
        for (var i = downLimit; i <= upperLimit; i++) {
            pages.push(i);
        }
        return pages;
    };

    self.GetPages = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        self.CurrentPage();
        self.TotalCount();

        if (self.PageCount() <= maxPageCount) {
            return ko.observableArray(self.generateAllPages());
        } else {
            return ko.observableArray(self.generateMaxPage());
        }
    });

    self.Update = function (e) {
        self.TotalCount(e.TotalCount);
        self.PageSize(e.PageSize);
        self.SetCurrentPage(e.CurrentPage);
    };

    self.GoToPage = function (page) {
        if (page >= self.FirstPage && page <= self.LastPage())
            self.SetCurrentPage(page);
    }

    self.GoToFirst = function () {
        self.SetCurrentPage(self.FirstPage);
    };

    self.GoToPrevious = function () {
        var previous = self.PreviousPage();
        if (previous != null)
            self.SetCurrentPage(previous);
    };

    self.GoToNext = function () {
        var next = self.NextPage();
        if (next != null)
            self.SetCurrentPage(next);
    };

    self.GoToLast = function () {
        self.SetCurrentPage(self.LastPage());
    };
}

var MainViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;       
    self.PageSize = ko.observable(10);
    self.AllData = ko.observableArray();
    self.PagaData = ko.observableArray();
    self.ActivePaging = ko.observable(false);       
    self.Paging = ko.observable(new PagingVm({
        pageSize: self.PageSize(),
        totalCount: self.AllData.length
    }));

    self.DeSelect = function (mainModel, event) {
        if (event.target.value === self.SelectedSearchOption()) {
            self.SelectedSearchOption(null);
            event.target.checked = false;
        }
        return true;
    };

    self.pageSizeSubscription = self.PageSize.subscribe(function (newPageSize) {
        self.Paging().Update({
            PageSize: newPageSize,
            TotalCount: self.AllData().length,
            CurrentPage: self.Paging().CurrentPage()
        });
        self.RenderAgain();
    });

    self.currentPageSubscription = self.Paging().CurrentPage.subscribe(function () {
        self.RenderAgain();
    });

    self.RenderAgain = function () {
        var result = [];
        var startIndex = (self.Paging().CurrentPage() - 1) * self.Paging().PageSize();
        var endIndex = self.Paging().CurrentPage() * self.Paging().PageSize();

        for (var i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++) {
            if (i < self.AllData().length)
                result.push(self.AllData()[i]);
        }
        self.PagaData(result);
    }

    self.dispose = function () {
        self.currentPageSubscription.dispose();
        self.pageSizeSubscription.dispose();
    }   
}

var vm = new MainViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
vm.RenderAgain();
```

});

```
<div data-bind="visible: ActivePaging" class="row" style="display: none;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
                <label>page size</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="number" min="1" data-bind="textInput:PageSize" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group marg-top-reports">
                    <!-- ko with:Paging()-->
                    <ul data-bind="visible: NeedPaging" class="pull-left pagination">
                        <li data-bind="css: { disabled: !FirstPageActive() }">
                            <a data-bind="click: GoToFirst">First</a>
                        </li>
                        <li data-bind="css: { disabled: !PreviousPageActive() }">
                            <a data-bind="click: GoToPrevious">Previous</a>
                        </li>
                        <!-- ko foreach: GetPages() -->
                        <li data-bind="css: { active: $parent.CurrentPage() === $data }">
                            <a data-bind="click: $parent.GoToPage, text: $data"></a>
                        </li>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                        <li data-bind="css: { disabled: !NextPageActive() }">
                            <a data-bind="click: GoToNext">Next</a>
                        </li>
                        <li data-bind="css: { disabled: !LastPageActive() }">
                            <a data-bind="click: GoToLast">Last</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>            
</div>
```

Comment: I get "jsonData is not defined" error when trying to load you page. Haven't you missed to include some fragment into your sample code?

Comment: Sounds like you already know the answer: *"It looks like the comment is being removed which is giving me the error."* If your production configuration is stripping all comments from the HTML it sends to the client, than that's where you need to look for a fix.

Comment: another way i can do this <!-- ko with:Paging()--> with out comment?

Comment: should not be needed jsonData